# How to load internet contents into local apache site?

Tags: php, apache, email

i got a big problem and can't find a solution how to fix that.
I got a local apache server (the standard one from macOS Sierra). The server is connected to the internet. There is a local site called "order-maintenance.php" where all users can order a maintenance for a machine.

The user fills out a formular and the script should send a mail via smtp (using pearl mail) to a predefined email-adresse. This part does not work. I found out, that the local apache server is not able to connect to the smtp-server. So I tried to load a webpage into an iframe just by using:

```
<?php echo <iframe src="https://www.google.de"></iframe>; ?>
```

But this also didn't worked. I came to the conclusion, that PHP can not connect to the internet. But why? My question is: Is there any way to allow a PHP-Script to load contents or connect to the internet?

If I try to e.g.

```
ping www.google.de
```

from the macOS Terminal, the connection is fine.

I'd be thankful for any solution or help,
thank you very much!

Comment: Your iframe test failed because of x-frame-options not because your php script couldn't connect to the internet

Comment: SMTP should work fine but mail() will not work .. so if you're using smtp you should be fine..I use gmail smtp all the time and it works fine on localhost as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is off on PhP, but overall you have too many variables to even decipher what you are trying to do.

First off you are using apache as a web server, have you verified that the PHP Module is running?

Simple way to check this would be to save a file with the following.

```
<?php 
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

Comment: this is barely worth a comment to request more info from OP, not an answer.

Comment: yes, php is running, i'm doing mysql queries all the time